# looking for remsh command on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access

On our local network we still have a couple of legacy HPUX 9 hosts which don't have ssh.
To do remote administration we used to use a Redhat Server with the remsh/rsh command.
Now the Redhat has been changed to Ubuntu.
Hostname and IP are the same as before but I cannot find any rsh / remsh package to run remsh commands.
I tried to use the dsh package but  dsh -r rsh  says ..port 22: connection refused
and  dhs -r remsh   says  ..Failed executing remsh with llexec call

Does anybody have a solution to get access to those old hosts?

Answer (score 1):

I found that rsh-client does what I need.
It installs netkit-rsh and some symlinks which supply rsh and rlogin commands.